# How to get current displayed Tab Index with jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, tabs, refresh

I am developping a web page usin html + PHP + jquery and I am facing the following problem.
The page uses jquery-1-7-2.js (I cannot upgrade for some historical reasons...).
I am using PHP and form to query a MySQL database and then diplay the result in different tabs (using jquery).

The problem is that I would like to be able to stay on the current active tab when refreshing the page (the form provocates an automatic refresh on change).

There is the type of code I am using:

```
<html>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="span12">

      <div class="well">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="span2">
            <form name="choice">
            <label>Choice :</label>
            <select name="menu" style="width:150px" onChange="refreshFormTechno(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="%">ALL</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice2">Choice 2</option>
            </select>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="MyTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Second Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>


      <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <div class="row">
        MY CODE TO DISPLAY IN TAB 1
      </div>
        </div>


        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <div class="row">
        MY CODE TO DISPLAY IN TAB 2
      </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
          <div class="row">
        MY CODE TO DISPLAY IN TAB 3
      </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">
function refreshFormTechno(value_id)
{
  document.location = './index.php?choice='+value_id;
}
</script>


</html>
```

If I change the script part by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">
function refreshFormTechno(value_id)
{
  //document.location = './index.php?choice='+value_id;
  var index = $('#MyTab a[href="#tab2"]').parent().index();
  alert(index);
}
</script>
```

I am able to get the Id of the tab I want (0 for tab1, 1 for tab2). But I cannot figure out how to get the Id of the active tab.

I found many threads about this type of problem and tried to test the code presented but it did not work.
I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">
function refreshFormTechno(value_id)
{
  //document.location = './index.php?choice='+value_id;
  var index = $('#MyTab').tabs('option', 'selected');
  alert(index);
}
</script>
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">
function refreshFormTechno(value_id)
{
  //document.location = './index.php?choice='+value_id;
  var index = $('#MyTab').parent.tabs('option', 'selected');
  alert(index);
}
</script>
```

with no result...

Knowing the current Tab Index would permit me to change the default active tab when reloading the entire page.
More than that it would permit me to load php scripts only when needed and limit the charging time of the page.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you hiding/showing the tabs? I assume you are using jquery hide() & show()?

Comment: I really am not familiar with jquery and do not get time to learn it so I am adding a GET parameter in my refresh URL and I set the default active tab using PHP and setting the "active" value on the correct one. It works and that is what I wanted, maybe it is not the best pratice but I really do not have time. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use the 'active' pane id?

```
var visiblePaneId = $('div.tab-pane.active').attr('id')
var activeTabIndex = $('#MyTab a[href="' + visiblePaneId + '"]').parent().index();
```

Or get the active tab:

```
var tabHref = $('li.active:first-child').attr('href'); //returns the anchor's href which has #
var activeTabIndex = $(tabHref).parent().index();
```

Comment: Thank you, first method works ! Only had to add # markup in href  `var visiblePaneId = $('div.tab-pane.active').attr('id');
var activeTabIndex = $('#MyTab a[href="#' + visiblePaneId + '"]').parent().index();`